# Show that $\sin47^\circ+\sin61^\circ-\sin11^\circ-\sin25^\circ=\cos7^\circ$

Tags: trigonometry

> Show that $$\sin47^\circ+\sin61^\circ-\sin11^\circ-\sin25^\circ=\cos7^\circ$$

---

NOTE: I have seen the other questions and solutions for this problem. I have a particular question if my idea has a potential.

I decided to rearrange the LHS (without a particular reason, it just felt right to me) as follows $$\begin{align}(&\sin47^\circ-\sin11^\circ)+(\sin61^\circ-\sin25^\circ)\\&=2\cos\frac{47^\circ+11^\circ}{2}\sin\frac{47^\circ-11^\circ}{2}+2\cos\frac{61^\circ+25^\circ}{2}\sin\frac{61^\circ-25^\circ}{2}\\&=2\cos29^\circ\sin18^\circ+2\cos43^\circ\sin18^\circ\\&=2\sin18^\circ(\cos29^\circ+\cos43^\circ)\\&=4\sin18^\circ\cos36^\circ\cos7^\circ\end{align}$$

If this won't work, what is the intuition that leads to the appropriate rearranging?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the value of $\sin 47^{\circ}+\sin 61^{\circ}- \sin25^{\circ} -\sin11^{\circ}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/769103/what-is-the-value-of-sin-47-circ-sin-61-circ-sin25-circ-sin11)

Comment: Searched using [approach0.xyz](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csin47%5E%5Ccirc%2B%5Csin61%5E%5Ccirc-%5Csin11%5E%5Ccirc-%5Csin25%5E%5Ccirc%3D%5Ccos7%5E%5Ccirc%24&p=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$4\sin18^\circ\cos36^\circ\cos7^\circ=\frac{4\sin18^\circ\cos18^\circ\cos36^\circ\cos7^\circ}{\cos18^\circ}=\frac{2\sin36^\circ\cos36^\circ\cos7^\circ}{\cos18^\circ}=\\
\frac{\sin72^\circ\cos7^\circ}{\cos18^\circ}=\cos7^\circ$$